# Conditional Font Color on value with Pipe Angular4

Tags: angular

I have a list populated by ngFor and field for each Item in that list that looks like this.

```
<p class="claimStatus"><i>{{merchantCard.merchantClaimStatus.claimed | merchStaus:merchantCard.merchantClaimStatus.inviteSent}}</i></p>
```

This field has my custom pipe applied to it. The possible outcomes are `claimed`, `unclaimed` and `invite sent`. I need to be able to apply a different font color for each outcome. I am wondering how this could be possible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can set using `[style.color]`

```
<p class="claimStatus" [style-color]='getColor(merchantCard.merchantClaimStatus)'>
    <i>
       {{merchantCard.merchantClaimStatus.claimed | 
                    merchStaus:merchantCard.merchantClaimStatus.inviteSent}}
    </i>
</p>
```

Typescript should have the method as

```
getColor(status){
  if(status.claimed){
     return 'blue'
  } else if(status.unclaimed){
     return 'red'   
  }
}
```

Note: I assume that `claimed` and `unclaimed` are boolean properties

Comment: Apologies I did not provide enough info. The pipe merchStatus, will give three possible results claimed, unclaimed and inviteSent. merchantClaimStatus.claimed and merchantClaimStatus.inviteSent are both boolean, which is why i am using the pipe.

Comment: can you create a working `plunker` so i can work on it and help you